# How to adapt my function so that i can have multiple calculations happen inside the one function

Tags: c, function, calculation

So i have this code for resistance conversions and i need to have all my calculations happen inside of 1 function, but im not sure on how to go about doing this, so here is a screenshot of the formulas.[Formulas for calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxbnE.png). Does anybody have any idea on how to do this any help would be great.
what i have commented out can be ignored as isnt related to the function calculations.

```
float conversions (float R1, float R2, float R3)
{
    //Star to Delta conversion
    //RA calculation
    return ((R1*R2+R2*R3+R3*R1)/R3);

    
}


int main(void){
    float R1,R2,R3;
    
    //printf("Please enter an S to convert Star to Delta, a D to convert Delta to Star, and Q to quit ");
    //char x = UserInput();
   // printf ("You selected %c\n", x);
    
    
    printf("Please enter a value for R1 R2 and R3 seperated by a space: ");
    scanf("%f %f %f", &R1, &R2, &R3);
    
    printf("\n %f", conversions (R1, R2, R3));  // test to ensure values were being passed to variables
```

Comment: Have you already been introduced to pointers, arrays or struct in your c course?

Comment: add a function of float type to calculate this :R1 = Ra*Rb/Ra+Rb+Rc and you change the order of the arguments (Ra,Rb,Rc) to calculate the others and also to calculete ((R2*R1+R2*R3+R3*R1)/R3)

Comment: Do you mean create a new function separate from the one I already have, because it is a requirement that all calculations are done within the same function

Answer (score 0):

*"adapt my function so that i can have multiple calculations happen inside the one function"*

Steps I would take to provide several calculation choices within a single call:

- declare a `int` variable: `int choice = 0;`
- optional - (but recommended) create a `struct` to contain input *and* results values of calculations.
- use `printf` (as you have) to instruct user what to do.
- use `scanf()` or `fgets()` to read input (assume [scanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) for rest of steps.)
- scan in user choice:  `int count = scanf(" %c", &choice);`
- verify `choice == 1`
- if `choice == 1` continue to a `switch()` statement, eg:

***Edit*** address OP comment

Here is a code example.
In this example all of the input work is done in main, but the calculations are all done in the function.  It makes use of a single variable (type `struct`) to simplify the arguments passed in the function.):

```
void calculations(Calc_s *in);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    Calc_s calc = {0};
    int choice;
    printf("Enter cconversion type:\n0 for 'D->S'\n1 for S->D  \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice) {
        case DELTA_STAR://D->S
            calc.t = DELTA_STAR;
            printf("Enter 3 R values separated by space:\n");
            scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &calc.s.Ra, &calc.s.Rb, &calc.s.Rc);
            calculations(&calc);
            printf("Results:\nR1: %lf\nR2: %lf\nR3: %lf\n", calc.d.R1, calc.d.R2, calc.d.R3);
            break;
        case STAR_DELTA://D->S
            calc.t = STAR_DELTA;
            printf("Enter 3 R values separated by space:\n");
            scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &calc.d.R1, &calc.d.R2, &calc.d.R3);
            calculations(&calc);
            printf("Results:\nRa: %lf\nRb: %lf\nRc: %lf\n", calc.s.Ra, calc.s.Rb, calc.s.Rc);
            break;
    }

    
    
    return 0;
}

void calculations(Calc_s *in)
{
    double temp = 0.0;
    switch(in->t) {
        case DELTA_STAR:
            temp = (in->s.Ra + in->s.Rb + in->s.Rc);
            in->d.R1 = (in->s.Ra * in->s.Rb)/temp;
            in->d.R2 = (in->s.Ra * in->s.Rc)/temp;
            in->d.R3 = (in->s.Rb * in->s.Rc)/temp;
            break;
        case STAR_DELTA:
            temp = (in->d.R1*in->d.R2 + in->d.R2*in->d.R3 + in->d.R3*in->d.R1);
            in->s.Ra = temp/in->d.R3;
            in->s.Rb = temp/in->d.R2;
            in->s.Rc = temp/in->d.R1;

            break;
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you just a few questions. Firstly, is this char variable to be declared in main.      Secondly, is this switch statement inside of my function.

Comment: @Dean - There are many ways.  This can be all in the _function_ that you are calling.  Or, can be adapted to move the components around, i.e. make the choice of which calculation in main, then pass it to the function as an argument.  For example:  `double * multi_calc(char choice, choice_s *calcs);`.  But both user input and calculation are needed at some point, and in some location whether part in `main` or all in the called function really depends on what you need to do.

Comment: I know i am asking a lot but could you please integrate the switch statment into the function cause ive tried and i am still struggling even with the code that you showed. Thanks in advance i really appreciate the help.

Comment: Im not trying to rush you at all just wondering how far you were through with the code?

Comment: @Dean - Thank you can also be expressed by marking as accepted (hollow check mark)  :)

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you:

```
float conversions (float R1, float R2,float R3)
{
    return R2*R1+R2*R3+R3*R1;
}

float conversions2(float R1, float R2,float R3)
{
    return R1+R2+R3;         
}

int main(void){
float R1,R2,R3;

float Ra,Rb,Rc;

printf("Please enter a value for R1 R2 and R3 seperated by a space: ");
scanf("%f %f %f", &R1, &R2, &R3);
printf("\n\n");
printf("Please enter a value for Ra Rb and Rc seperated by a space: ");
scanf("%f %f %f", &Ra, &Rb, &Rc);
printf("\n %f", conversions (R1, R2, R3)/R1);  // test to ensure values were being passed to variables

printf("\n %f", conversions (R2, R2, R2)/R2);

printf("\n %f", conversions (R2,R2,R2)/R3);


printf("\n %f", (Ra*Rb)/conversions2 (Ra,Rb,Rc));

printf("\n %f",(Ra*Rc)/ conversions2 (Ra,Rb,Rc));

printf("\n %f",(Rb*Rc)/conversions2 (Ra,Rb,Rc));

}
```